# double: Roundaway from zero java

Tags: java, double, rounding

this may be a trivial question but I need to round a double away from zero - and I can't seem to find a method that does that easily - i know i could implement it myself but I'd only do that if it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Some input/output examples please.

Comment: [Probably already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: You could have written that function is less time than it took you to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) and [`Math.floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29):

```
(x > 0) ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x)
```

If `x` is positive, we "round up" using `ceil`; if `x` is negative (or zero) we "round down" using `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already suggested ceil and floor combination:

`Math.ceil(Math.abs(x))*Math.signum(x);`

It rounds up the absolute value, then puts the sign back by multiplying by `Math.signum(x)`.